# Django custom user admin change_password

Tags: python, django

I'm successfully using a custom user model with django. 
The last thing to get working is the "AdminChangePasswordForm" for superusers to change any users password.

currently the change password link from admin:myapp:user gives a 404

The answer.

Override get_urls

and override UserChangeForm to have the correct url.

Comment: can you post your user model?

Comment: yes, not all of it but you can see the general idea

Answer (score 3):

So I had similar problem. When I tried to change user password from admin I got url to "/admin/accounts/siteuser/password/" (siteuser is the name of my custom user model) and 404 error with this message: "user object with primary key u'password' does not exist."
The investigation showed that the problem was due to bug in django-authtools (1.4.0) as I used NamedUserAdmin class to inherit from.

So the solution is either (if you need to inherit from any custom UserAdmin like NamedUserAdmin from django-authtools):

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm
from authtools.admin import NamedUserAdmin
class SiteUserAdmin(NamedUserAdmin):
    ...
    form = UserChangeForm
    ...
```

or just inherit from default django UserAdmin:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
class SiteUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    pass
```

Comment: This answer is pure gold. I have been digging for this beauty for several hours. Thanks.

Comment: Inheriting from the default django UserAdmin saves me!

Answer (score 2):

It seems it's a "bug" in [1.7.x](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.7.x/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L79), and fixed in [1.8.x](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.8.x/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L81), which set the url name, so you do have to override `get_urls()`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as AuthUserAdmin
from django.conf.urls import url


class UserAdmin(AuthUserAdmin):
    def get_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r'^(.+)/password/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.user_change_password), name='auth_user_password_change'),
        ] + super(UserAdmin, self).get_urls()
```

URL:

```
password_change_url = urlresolvers.reverse('admin:auth_user_password_change', args=(1,))
```

Comment: Ok I'm using 1.8. Will try it ASAP and let you know

Comment: Where does the URL go? I added it to custom UserAdmin but it can't reverse the URL. even changing the "auth" to "users" (my app name) gives the same. Also, what is with the static arg of 1?

Comment: If you are using 1.8 or don't need to get password_change_url by user id, the answer is not useful to you. The "1" is just a example. Can you post your `UserAdmin`? The change password link: https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.8.x/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L103 , UserChangeForm for UserAdmin: https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.8.x/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L57

Comment: Ok if I just add the url into UserAdmin get_urls, I now get "user object with primary key u'password' does not exist." on django 1.8.5

Comment: Got it. It needed to be \"./password/\" not \"../password/\" in the form.

Comment: It seems something wrong with the url. The url in my project looks like this: /admin/users/user/49/password/. The pk should be the number in the url, now the string "password" is uesed to get the user object: https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.8.x/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L127