# Django Admin Change password link broken

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Example for user "Bob"
Django Admin: `Home › Authentication and Authorization › Users › Bob`

When modifying a user in Django Admin interface, under the password it says:

> Raw passwords are not stored, so there is no way to see this user's password, but you can change the password using **this form**.

However, the `this form` link fails with a `Page not found 404`, and the address is:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/password/`

Whereas the correct URL (which works) should be:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/auth/user/40/password/`

After some searching I found: `Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py:129` :

```
class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField(
        label=_("Password"),
        help_text=_(
            "Raw passwords are not stored, so there is no way to see this "
            "user's password, but you can change the password using "
            "<a href=\"{}\">this form</a>."
        ),
    )
```

But I dont see how the change password link is set in the href, it looks blank to me. I also dont want to change the Django sourcecode because then the same bug will manifest when there are updates. How to I get the link to point to the change password page which works?

Answer (score 2):

You are not using this `UserChangeForm`. For custom user admin, follow this documentation [Customizing Authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a custom user model or user admin? If that's the case, your admin class should be `BaseUserAdmin` or inherited from that.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be something very obscure. So after a lot of reverting and modifying new config files to work with old code, managed to narrow it done to a single line in my: `templates\admin\base.html`, the first line of the `<head>` section was:

```
<base href="/"><!-- For CSP stylesheet href links to pass MIME TYPE checks -->
```

The `<base>` tag:

> specify a default URL and a default target for all links on a page

Answer (score 0):

The link in the href seems to be set in the `UserChangeForm`'s `__init__` method:

```py
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    password = self.fields.get('password')
    if password:
        password.help_text = password.help_text.format('../password/') # <-- here
    # ...
```

I'm not sure why yours was taking you all the way back to `localhost:8000/password/` as it's meant to go up one "directory" (from `/admin/auth/user/40/change` to `/admin/auth/user/40`) and then down to `/admin/auth/user/40/password/`.

The other implication of this href format is that if your URL structure doesn't have a trailing slash (eg `/.../users/40/change`), the `../password/` a. will take you to `/.../users/password/` and you'll get a "No user with PK=password" error, and b. won't work with your URL structure anyway because it's added a trailing slash.

It does seem curious that Django doesn't have a way to override it (eg by passing the `UserChangeForm` a `password_url` or something). There might be a bug report / feature suggestion here...

As for actually dealing with it, one option, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33230467/584026), is to manipulate your URL config to set the password change URL manually and point it to the relevant admin / auth view.

Unfortunately that doesn't help if you are subclassing or using the form elsewhere. In that case, the only solution I've thought of so far is to manually replace it in your subclass's `__init__` like so:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import forms as auth_forms

class UserEditForm(auth_forms.UserChangeForm):    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        password = self.fields.get('password')
        if password:
            password.help_text = password.help_text.replace(
                '../password/', kwargs.pop('password_url', './password'))
```

Unfortunately you have to use `.replace` as you can't reformat the help text once the `super().__init__` has formatted it, and you can't do it before calling `super().__init__` as you won't be able to access the field. This method does at least allow for passing a `password_url` as an argument to the form, and otherwise defaults to `./password` which will work for URL structures without a trailing slash.